# Selenium Webdriver_How to Search & Click particular Records in Search Fields by taking input from Excel Sheet

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have started to automate my application using Selenium Webdriver. I stuck one of below point for that I need some guidance .I'm trying to search particular records in the search fields (I have taken search text input from excel sheet) and as result the search returns me few records which is matching with the inputs i have provided using execl sheet .so now I want to select the one of the records displayed in search result. 
im able to search text but stuck how to select or click that records.

here is scripts I have designed for same:

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#txtSearchKeyword")).sendKeys(Sheet.getCell(3, i).getContents());`

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are talking in context of **Autocomplete Search**, like Google uses. I am basing my answer on that.

Say, you have searched for text **'Stack'** and the result you got are **'Stack1, Stack2, Stack3, Stack4'**

Now, say you want to click on **'Stack2**. For that you can use the below code:

```
driver.findElement("//*[.='Stack2']").click();
```

**Note:** Here, the element with exact text as **'Stack2'** is located and clicked. So, the text from the search must be exactly this. Furthermore, no other element in the webpage must have this text, apart from the search result. 
You can anyway modify the above xpath with respect to the search results list. Say, **if the search results are wrapped in a div element with id 'list'**, then you can use the below code:

```
driver.findElement("//div[@id=['list']//[.='Stack2']").click();
```